# How do I build the node title from field values when saving the node?

Tags: 8, nodes, rules

I have a content type (*supertest*) with the *Category* and *Section* fields, which are taxonomy term references. Every user has a *Display name* field.
I need to update the node titles when saving the nodes using *[category] - [section]: [author.display_name]* as format.

I've tried to add a rule, *Display message* action (just to test) on *Before content save* event, but it doesn't work. I can't figure out how to use the category field value to set the node title.

How can I make rules to change the node title?

Comment: Can you this on After saving new content event. You need to create two rules .First for save new content and second for updating content.

Comment: One thing you cannot set node title as your desired format because rules Data selector not allow to do that.

Comment: This would be easy enough to do in code, considering Rules has no stable release.

Comment: I've updated the question title once again to get to the root of the problem. If you find that it doesn't match your problem, please change it back :)

Comment: @PankajYogi I take you created the demo with simplytest.me, didn't you? In that case, it's worth remembering the site will be deleted in 12/24 hours. (I bet the second, but I don't recall it right now.)

Comment: @kiamlaluno Sorry For that . I will take care next time.

Comment: @PankajYogi You didn't do anything wrong. Just remember to say the link is for a simplytest.me site. Differently, users could find suspicious you give credentials for a site.

Comment: (Actually, my comment was also to avoid users would flag the comment.)

Comment: ok Sure I will do that next time. Thankyou for your support . I am learning from, You are like my mentor.

Comment: @Kevin, could you show example of hook validate/submit for this?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The answer is very easy to accomplish by just following the below steps.

First of all, with all my respect to the glory of the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) modules but yet it is not ready for development on Drupal 8 Website otherwise you will be facing tons of issues and you will spend most of your time within the issue page.

So, here comes the [Business rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/business_rules), the alternative workflowing D8 module.

**What is [Business rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/business_rules) module:**

> The Business Rules module is inspired on Rules module and allow site
>   administrators to define conditionally actions execution based on
>   events. It's based on variables and completely build for Drupal 8.
>   This module has a fully featured user interface to completely allow
>   the site administrator to understand and create the site business
>   rules.   It's also possible to extend it by creating new ReactsOn
>   Events, Variables, Actions and Conditions via plugins.

I strongly advice you to read the [**documentation**](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/business-rules), so you get more familiar with it.

**Why using [Business rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/business_rules) modules ?**

Business rules modules will not only help you to achieve your above question but will give your website a powerful way to execute **actions** based on **events and conditions** defined by you as administrator.

Using and getting familiar with such great module, will save you spending time trying to create a custom module to add some extra features to your website while you can do it with few clicks using **Business Rules** modules.

**How to auto-generate the title based on node's fields values after saving the node:**

1) Install and Enable the:

- [Business rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/business_rules) Module.
- [Dbug](https://www.drupal.org/project/dbug) Module. (Dependency for business rules module)
- [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) Module. (Specific for your case)

2) Goto: `/admin/config/workflow/business_rules/collection`

3) Under the **Actions** Tab, Click on **+Add Action**

4) **Type:** Set Field Value

5) Here is where the magic will happen:
   - **Label:** Change the Title field based on other field values.

- **Description:** Action to Change the Title field based on other field values.
- **Target Entity Type:** Content
- **Target Bundle:** Supertest
- **Field:** Text (Plain): Title [Title]
- **Value:** `[node:category:entity:name] - [node:section:entity:name] - [node:author]`
- Save the action

6) Goto: `/admin/config/workflow/business_rules/collection`

7) Under the **Rules** Tab, Click on **+Add Rule**

8) **Reacts on event:** Before Saving Entity

- **Label:** Before saving entity of type node (supertest)
- **Description:** Before saving entity of type node (supertest)
- **Target Entity Type:** Content
- **Target Bundle:** Supertest
- **In the Items Section:** Click on **add action** link.
- **Popup window will open:** Click on the desired action's title to add it to your current rule. (In your case, there is only one action available so click on its title)
- Save the Rule

**Testing the rule:**

1) Goto: `/node/add/superset`

2) **Title:** This title should change after saving this node

3) Set your taxonomy fields as desired

4) Save the node.

5) Check your new title.

Voila!

Feel free to ask for help if you faced some troubles.

Comment: I was really hoping those modules will be available for Drupal 9, I got disappointed!.

Answer (score 4):

Could be a job for [Automatic Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel). Actually I'm using it that way – in production (though it has no stable release yet it works just fine).

> "Automatic Entity Label" is a small and efficient module that allows
>   hiding of entity label fields. To prevent empty labels it can be
>   configured to generate the label automatically by a given pattern.

You can define tokens from which the title will be built. An you can optionally set the title field to be always hidden on the node form. I'd also recommend to make the fields mandatory (required) that you use to build the title.

[image]